# Earned Creditor and Bluebook badge for same answer and cited topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I earned a Creditor *and* a Bluebook badge for [the same citation in the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783781/enumerate-keys-and-values-of-idictionary-when-i-dont-know-type-of-values/38784075#38784075).

As the description states:

- Creditor is awarded for the "First citation of a topic or example you haven't contributed to...", and
- Bluebook is awarded for the "First citation of a topic or example you've contributed to."

So how can I get both of them for the same linked topic?

---

Additional info: the Bluebook badge was awarded at August 5, the Creditor badge right now (August 8). Maybe my contribution was removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The early version of the query behind the Creditor badge didn't correctly take contributions (or lack thereof) into account.

That's since been fixed, so all future badges should be awarded only for linking to topics that the answerer hadn't edited.